# Creating Zabbix trigger with item from different template

Tags: monitoring, zabbix

I have an item in `Template A` and would like to have a trigger for only a subset of hosts that have the `Template A` configured for them.

I would not like to create the trigger on `Template A` and manually disable it for the hosts I don't need it for (I have too many hosts, might need additional triggers, might need to fine-tune (that re-enables them)), so I created `Template B` and assigned to the hosts I'd like to have the new trigger.

I tried to...

- create a trigger with expression `{Template B:item}>value`, but Zabbix complained that `Template B` has no such item (which is true if only considering this template but `Template A` is also assigned to all hosts). And I cannot create the item in `Template B` as it conflicts with the other.
- create a trigger on `Template B` and reference the item in `Template A`, but the trigger moved to `Template A` and got applied to all hosts.
- create a macro for `Template B`, assigned it to the hosts I need, and added a new trigger to `Template A` with expression `{$MACRO_NAME}=1 and {Template A:item}>limit`.

What is the proper solution for this case?

(If it matters, the server and hosts are running Zabbix version 3.2.1 and Debian Linux.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Macro](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.2/manual/config/macros).
define a macro in your template and change value of this according of host.

you can change value of macro with [zabbix api](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/api/reference/usermacro).

Comment: I have tried this earlier (see the third "i tried to" part) but maybe it took more time than I expected and left it there, now I realized they worked, so I am marking this as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Normal flow is this:

1. Link `Template B` to `Template A`.
2. Apply `Template B` only on the required host.
3. Create a trigger for the item in `Template A` into `Template B`.
4. The trigger (of step 3) should be invoked only for the required host (of step 2) and not where `Template B` is not applied.

The claim that `the trigger moved to Template A and got applied to all hosts` doesn't seem correct.

Comment: It is correct, since it also happened to me. Creating a trigger in a template referencing an item in another linked template moves the new trigger into the linked template.

Comment: Follow-up: I discovered that if your trigger in `Template B` references an item in `Template A` and includes `Template A` in the item's path (ex. `last(/Template A/proc.num)>1000`, then the trigger will be created in `Template A`. However if you change the path (ex `last(/Template B/proc.num)>1000`), then it's created in the correct template.

Comment: Maybe you are correct. Its really too long, and I don't remember seeing the option to set up a custom item path.